# DataAnnotations Dispaly Name in MVC show wrong Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

```
 public decimal Id { get; set; }
 [Display(Name = "موضوع")]
 public string Title { get; set; }
```

[image]

show me this result i used

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
and
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
  </system.web>
```

but it doesn't work why? I use DataAnnotations in mvc4 but don't know why mvc5 have this problem?

Comment: what is your expected behavior ? how does your razor code looks like ?

Comment: <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>

Comment: what is your expected behaviour ?

Comment: to show this موضوع not ãæÖæÚ this is wrong

Comment: Works fine for me. What browser locale are you using ?